# How to create fungsion button save, from one2many to one2many other?

Tags: odoo

I try create one2many which take from ony2many other with button save,  this for version odoo. It is possible, and if yes, how to do that.

Thanks for your contribution.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

No that was not Possible

syntax :

```
class openerp.fields.One2many(comodel_name=None, inverse_name=None, string=None, **kwargs)[source]
```

One2many field; the value of such a field is the recordset of all the records in comodel_name such that the field inverse_name is equal to the current record.

> **Parameters**
>     comodel_name -- name of the target model (string)
>
> **> inverse_name -- name of the inverse Many2one field in comodel_name
>   (string)**
>
> domain -- an optional domain to set on candidate values on the client
>   side (domain or string)
>
> context -- an optional context to use on the client side when handling
>   that field (dictionary)
>
> auto_join -- whether JOINs are generated upon search through that
>   field (boolean, by default False)
>
> limit -- optional limit to use upon read (integer)

The attributes comodel_name and inverse_name are mandatory except in the case of related fields or field extensions.